# Proper way to post changes to packagist?

Tags: git, github, composer-php, packagist

I recently took 'ownership' of a git repository for some code made for my company by a third party. I finally needed to update something in the package yesterday and realized I also needed ownership of the packagist package details. Upon contacting the developer, he just removed his version of the libraries on packagist and I re-created them from my own account.
It seems to work fine for the existing code, but now I'm trying to update it.  I made the updates on github, added tags for both v0.0.6 and 0.0.6 and pushed a new branch "0.0.6" then updated packagist.

But it shows up with 0.0.6.x-dev

And our live site is set not to accept development branches (and the staging branch is configured to match live) so composer won't download the update.

I've checked a number of threads and while I see many references to the fact packagist defaults to -dev on new branches, I have yet to find any instructions on how to change the default or otherwise change the branch to be non-dev.

What is the correct process for posting a non-dev update to packagist?